# Availability Query Based on Inventory without Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to build a query that will display availability results from a table based on a total amount (not dates) inputted by the user. The price fluctuates based on the date, like a hotel. The main goal is to present available dates just based on the amount a user is willing to spend but not on actual date availability.  The dates are irrelevant but they do need to be presented back consecutively in a range. Additionally, needs to work on SQL 2000.  I'm can't wrap my head on how to pull this one off.

Sample data:

```
date     |  amount per night

1/1/15   | 12
1/2/15   | 13
1/3/15   | 12
1/4/15   | 5
```

So if a user inputs 30 the results would return as follows:

```
date range      | total

1/2/15 - 1/4/15 | 30   
1/1/15 - 1/2/15 | 26  
1/2/15 - 1/3/15 | 25   
1/3/15 - 1/4/15 | 17
```

Comment: Are you trying to determine all possible combinations where the sum of dates in a sequence are <= the input parameter? And if that is the case why would you not get 1/3 - 1/4 returned? It is a viable range. I have a feeling that what you are trying to do is far more complicated than you realize.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly the case. I will update the question to include that example range in the result sample too (d'oh).

Comment: What is the max and min price per day, it can help in figuring out the max date range possible per amount.

Comment: There is no min and max per day, just one price per day.

Comment: I don't think you understood my meaning, for ANY given day, what is the lowest price you would get, and what is the highest price you could get, you could use that to try to figure out versus the cash being passed in the minimum and maximum number of days you can get and cut off checking all date ranges possible.

Comment: Each day of the year would have an assigned value - lets say the lowest possible value is 10 and the highest is 50. The goal is to return date ranges of all kinds for the amount you can spend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL 2000 you don't have the OVER clause, so a WHILE loop is your best (only?) option.

Use a temp table to start with the two-day options.

```
set @numdates = 1
select d1.[date] as startdate,
    d2.[date] as enddate,
    d1.price + d2.price as price,
    2 as numdates
into #stays
from dates d1
join dates d2 on d2.date = dateadd(day,1,d1.date)
where d1.price + d2.price <= @cash
```

Now loop through this:

```
while (@@rowcount > 0)
begin
    set @numdates = @numdates + 1

    insert  #stays
    select d1.startdate as startdate,
        d2.[date] as enddate,
        d1.price + d2.price as price,
        d1.numdates + 1 as numdates
    from #stays d1
    join dates d2 on d2.date = dateadd(day,1,d1.enddate)
    where d1.price + d2.price <= @cash
    and d1.numdates = @numdates
end
```

Or something like that. I haven't tested it (just typed on my phone)

Comment: Pass in `@cash`, and declare `@numdates`. And use the right column names, which hopefully don't actually have spaces. If it's homework, let me know how I scored. ;)

Comment: This only seems to work for 2 day intervals, the while loop doesn't seem to fire off additional days in SQL 2000 Query Analyzer.

Comment: Ok... works for me. You do have to run both blocks of code together. Otherwise @@rowcount isn't > 0 when it starts, and it doesn't enter the loop.

Comment: Recursive CTE, the SQL Server 2000 style.

Comment: @Andriy - totally! And in fact, this can sometimes work more nicely than a CTE, as it doesn't force it to use a Nested Loop.